# How to stay on same page if a record delete from table in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have multiple records in my database table Now, what I want when I click on a specific record delete button then the record will be deleted and the page will be stay on the same page without redirect anywhere. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

controller: UserController.php

```
public function delete_emp($id)
{
    DB::delete('delete from emp where id = ?',[$id]);
}
```

view: emp-list.blade.php

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($result as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row->fname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->phone }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{url('/delete_emp')}}/{{ $row->id }}" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('are you sure')">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

route/web.php

```
Route::get('delete_emp/{id}','UserController@delete_emp');
```

Comment: You better fire ajax to achieve the same

Comment: ok, but is there any way by doing this @quickSwap

Answer (score 0):

in your UserController.php, just add one line below the query

```
public function delete_emp($id)
{
    DB::delete('delete from emp where id = ?',[$id]);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```